# Stretched image on display

Tags: raspbian, display

I have a 7" display attached to my RPI.

Controller Board VS-TY2662-V1
Lcd Panel AT070TN92
Running raspbian.

In theory it has 800x480. I run a website I kiosk mode on it. If I use fixed height and width on that very resolution it's too big for the screen. So I ended up using trial and error to figure out the right resolution (720x575).

The main issue is that the display is stretched, i.e. it shows a 4:3 image on that 16:9 display without borders. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What does `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s` show?

Comment: `state 0x12001a [HDMI CEA (17) RGB lim 4:3], 720x576 @ 50.00Hz, progressive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your post whether 720x576 is the default, or whether you have manually set it.

AFAIK there is no 800*480 CEA or DVT mode (incidentally this is 5:3 NOT 16:9).

You could try setting the display as described in http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679

The normal settings can be found on http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options

Comment: I didn't set the resolution manually. Wouldn't make sense after all to use a wrong resolution. Will try it later. The 720x576 was a guess using trial and error so it's 720x575 as stated in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) To be precise this comment in the board mentioned above helped. http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=235430#p235430